# Google Cloud - Spreading clients across projects and monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We use google cloud servers to host websites from different clients. This was a great way for us to move away from the vertical approach of having a large web hosting server, and towards many smaller instances.

A couple of days ago i came across [this](http://www.fredtrotter.com/2016/08/22/google-intrusion-detection-problems/) on Hacker News. Basically something was compromised in his project, and google shut the whole project down rather than just the instance that was infected.

This leads us to believe that we should have each client on their own project so as if one client is compromised through failing to maintain their website, all the others are not effected, however this poses problems with monitoring machine performance through stack driver (As we can't monitor multiple projects from the same screen)

Can anyone think of a way to mitigate this? A better way of monitoring? Or possibly upgrading support to at least silver to get some feedback from google when they find an infection?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider to use an external monitoring tool, there are many that are able to monitor whatever you want by using different ways. For example, through stack driver API or via web, or directly reporting from your cloud machines.

Just to give you an example, I use Pandora FMS to monitor several structures (including cloud) and all is centralized in one web interface. You can try with others like Nagios or Zabbix too, but obviusly i recommend you the solution I'm using (Here is a [link](https://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/server-monitoring/) if you want to take a look).

Hope this can help!